# Moved VBA function and macro to new workbook off network drive but now returning #Name? instead of proper value

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel macro that uses a function. Currently, the file is on a network drive. Data is pasted to the Excel file (new tab each time) and the macro is run with no problems (account number successfully pulled from larger data set).

In my effort to move the macro from a network drive to the cloud and run the macro from a separate Excel file (the file that contains the initial data dump i.e. no pasting data to file where macro lives), the portion of the macro that uses the function is now returning #NAME? instead of the proper numerical values. I am totally stumped as to why this is happening.

Literally any help at all is appreciated!

**Function**

```
Function onlynumbers(ByVal ref As String)
Dim rx As Object

Set rx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

With rx
    .Pattern = "\D"
    .Global = True
    onlynumbers = .Replace(ref, "")
End With
End Function
```

**Macro (see 'Fix Account Number' section)**

```
Sub FORMAT()

'Remove extra rows on TOP
Rows("1:6").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

'Remove Extra Columns
Columns("A:H").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Columns("B:O").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Columns("C:J").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    
'Extract Account Number from OBI Field
Range("C2").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=MID(B2,SEARCH(""79*"",B2),8)"

'Autofill Formula
Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("C2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("C2:C" & lastRow)

'Fix Account Number
Range("D2").Select
    ActiveCell.Formula = "=onlynumbers(C2)"
Range("D2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("D2:D" & lastRow)

Range("E2").Select
    ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(LEN(D2)<6,"""",D2)"
Range("E2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("E2:E" & lastRow)

Range("E2:E" & lastRow).Select
    Selection.Copy
Range("B2:B" & lastRow).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

Columns("C:D").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

Columns("C:C").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

'Column Headers
Range("A1:G1").Value = Array("Amount", "Account", "Transaction Type", "Description", "Cash Type", "Post Date", "Tax Year")

'Switch Amount and Account Columns
Columns("B:B").Select
    Selection.Cut
Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    
'Set Transaction Type
Range("C2").Value = "Deposit to Account - Wire received"
Range("C2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("C2:C" & lastRow)

'Set Description
Range("D2").Value = "$TranDesc$ of $CashAmount$"
Range("D2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("D2:D" & lastRow)

'Set Cash Type
Range("E2").Value = "Principal"
Range("E2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("E2:E" & lastRow)

'Set Post Date
Range("F2").Select
    ActiveCell.Formula = "=TODAY()"
Range("F2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("F2:F" & lastRow)

'Set Tax Year
Range("G2").Select
    ActiveCell.Formula = "=YEAR(TODAY())"
Range("G2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("G2:G" & lastRow)

'Final Formatting
Range("C1:G1").Select
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
Columns("C:G").Select
    Columns("C:G").EntireColumn.AutoFit

'Reset Selection
Range("A1").Select


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you also move your function, or just the macro?

If not, putting the function in the same place as the macro (just after `End Sub` on a new line) should fix things if you need the macro to refer to the function.

However, to use the function in a worksheet (which it looks like you are doing), the workbook containing the cell with the fixed account number needs to also contain the function. That way, the account number cell can use the function.

The error NAME is because the cell formula cannot find a defined name `onlynumbers`.

You could also try defining the function with the Name Manager instead of in VBA, but **the best way might be** to just change the formula in that cell to do what you want it to do using the built-in Excel functions. You could then update the macro to input this new formula at that line.

Comment: I did move the function as well as the macro, but your second point is why I think it stopped working. My goal was to run the macro via a button which refers to the macro and function that are in the cloud. The workbook that contains the account number is on the local machine because it is generated automatically from a source location. That’s why originally the data was pasted into the workbook and then the macro was run.

Comment: In that case your best bet might be to avoid using the  custom function and instead get a formula in that cell to do the same thing.

Comment: I appreciate the responses!

Comment: No problem, have a go at using a formula to reduce the account number cell format to just numbers, and then post a new question if you get stuck with it.